# Using WillCascadeOnDelete on ASP.MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

From the code snippet below :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany(e => e.ProductPictures)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Product)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Which is `WillCascadeOnDelete` referring to?

`Product` has

```
-ProductID
-ProductNumber
-ProductDescription
-Cost
-UnitPrice
-OnHandQty
-StartDate
-CreateDate
```

`ProductPicture` has

```
-ProductPictureId
-ProductId
-IsThumb
-SortOrder
-ProductPictureNote
```

which means that `ProductPicture` is the dependent one. Is `WillCascadeOnDelete` referring to `Product`? meaning that if `Product` is deleted then the `ProductId` property of the `ProductPicture` will be set to null.

Answer (score 0):

"Cascading delete" is a configuration of a relationship, not of an entity/table. Hence WillCascadeOnDelete is a method of ascadableNavigationPropertyConfiguration.

It means that if a Product deleted from the database, it's ProductPictures should not be deleted together with the Product. That's a property of this specific relationship, not of the Product table.